# Run Time error while performing Toast Application in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.tejeswar.project0, PID: 8051
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tejeswar.project0/com.example.tejeswar.project0.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:105)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.tejeswar.project0.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:19)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1088)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
11-01 21:11:03.260 8051-8051/com.example.tejeswar.project0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Comment: Even it's evident from the stacktrace what the problem is, please add the relevant code in your question - `MainActivity.java:19`

Comment: Don't link to your project. Edit the relevant parts of your code into the question. Also just look at the stack trace, it pretty much explains exactly what the problem is: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`. In other words you are calling `getApplicationContext()` on an object which is `null`.

Comment: add your code to .. its not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getApplicationContext()` too early in your activity object construction phase `<init>` i.e. constructor or member variable initialization.

Move the code that needs a valid `Context` to `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle.